# Bitmask to Array Index

Tags: c++, indexing, bitmask

Is there a simple way to convert a bitmask in to an array index?

ie. If i've got an enum

```
a = 0x01,
b = 0x02,
c = 0x04,
d = 0x08,
e = 0x10, 
etc
```

and I want to store releated data in an array, is there a simple way such that i can convert a to 0, b to 1, c to 2. etc?

Many thanks

Comment: You may want to check this out: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/MS/Internal/UncommonValueTable.cs,93b81e5e13cb3600 (maintains a bitmask for different sizes of array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
r =   ln base 2 
and programmatically,

unsigned int v=yourEnumValue;
unsigned r = 0; 
while (v >>= 1) 
{
   r++;
}

r is your answer
```

Comment: Does someone know a faster more low level solution?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but why don't you just take a 2-base log?

Comment: Ah yes, natural log. That's what I was looking for. I thought there'd be something, just couldn't remeber what it was. Cheers.

Comment: That's not a natural log. A natural log is log base e.

Answer (score 3):

Log<sub>2</sub> n?

Answer (score 2):

I dont know a simple solution like you asked for, but why not just use a map instead an array?

Should work without any magic conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Use a std::map:

```
#include <map>

std::map <my_enum, my_datatype> m;
m[ a ] = whatever;
```

Comment: I don't want to use a map, as i dont want the overhead of storing the key.

Comment: The overhead for an enum would be tiny - and you have to compare it with the overhead of calculating the index.